# Iterate over Pages library and get each item's properties

Tags: list, publishing-site, publishing-page

I need to use C# to iterate over the publishing Pages library items on SharePoint 2010 and get their properties. For example, I need to get the item's filename (if it's a file) and detect if it's a folder and get its name. There could be folders within folders, so this might require recursion.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest possible code to just get page and folder names is:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myCoolSite"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList pageList = web.Lists["MyCoolPageLibrary"];
        // Get items
        foreach(SPListItem item in pageList.Items)
        {
            // item.File.Name 
        }
        // Get folders
        foreach(SPListItem folder in pageList.Folders)
        {
            // folder.Title
        }
    }
}
```

However this is not best practice: [Read: Best Practices: Common Coding Issues When Using the SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949%28v=office.12%29.aspx#WorkingWithFoldersLists) for more info on this subject. It really depends on your specific needs but enumerating all items and/or folders can easily lead to poor performance and even exceptions and/or timeouts (if working with large lists)

**Followup**

I have found one nice article about folder hierarchies with code examples:

- [Traversing SharePoint List Folder Hierarchies](http://blog.krichie.com/2007/01/30/traversing-sharepoint-list-folder-hierarchies/)

Comment: Thanks, Vedran. We need to go over a relatively small list of pages (a dozen or so) and one or two folders with a few pages in them. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: How do you get the various attributes of a publishing Page, such as its Title?

Comment: item.Title or item["Title"]. You can get even file name by using item["FileLeafRef"]. Just use item["Internal or display field name"]. You can do `foreach` on item.Fields and see what you can get.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking followups... If a folder contains pages, will you loop over them in the second `foreach`? I need to know which folder structure a publishing page is in. Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my answer with link to one interesting article on this subject. I think you can find all answers to your followups there. But if you need any additional help feel free to ask.